# How to set Total Transactions while using loop sampler

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I need to set my script to keep total transactions = 30 for 15 min.

My script looks like:

Thread Group (x) ==> Loop Controller (200 times) ==> Dummy Sampler ==> Synchronizing Timer (30)

The result shows total transaction much higher, I guess it's because the loop controller and the Sync Timer.
How can I set it correctly?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by "total transactions"? If you want to send 30 requests in 15 minutes more or less evenly distributed you need to use [Constant Throughput Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-throughput) instead of the Synchronizing Timer and configure it to send 2 requests per minute.

If you want 30 transactions in total as fast as it possible - set the number of loops to the 30 divided by the number of threads (virtual users) i.e.

- 1 user - 30 loops
- 2 users - 15 loops
- 3 users - 10 loops
- etc.

The [Synchronizing Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer) just releases the requests in batches of 30 concurrent ones so you're basically sending requests in [spikes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_performance_testing#Spike_testing)

Comment: more details: I have two csv files: 1. customers(150) 2. date range(200). The Thread Group represent number of customers. The loop controller represent dates range . For each customer i need to create 200 policies. My question, how to set total transactions to be 30 per sec.

Comment: I added Constant Throughput Timer and set to 1800 per min + all active threads. so far it looks OK. I'll update. Is it the right way to do it?

Comment: As soon as it "looks OK" it's "right". You can also take a look at [Precise Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Precise_Throughput_Timer) and/or [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-shaping-timer-plugin)